# How to access a WSL instance from another?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am upgrading my WSL2 instance from Debian 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, because I need some newer packages.

How do I copy files and directories from Debian to Ubuntu, preserving the permissions and owner? (uid and gid are the same in the two Linuxes.)

Copying to windows first changes the permissions and owner of files.

`explorer.exe` also changes permissions and owner.

Preferably, I'd also like to avoid having to create a shared disk image file that I could mount from Debian and Ubuntu in turn.

I'd like something simpler, like accessing the second WSL instance directly from the first, e.g.,

```sh
    $ cp -a <Debian>/myfiles/ <Ubuntu>/myfiles
```

Is this possible?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67900684/how-to-access-wsl-from-within-a-wsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tar. It will preserve all the file metadata.

In <Debian>, create `myfiles.tar.gz`:

```
tar zcvf myfiles.tar.gz myfiles
```

Copy `myfiles.tar.gz` to your windows drive e.g. with `explorer.exe` or with `/mnt/c`, and then copy `myfiles.tar.gz` to <Ubuntu>. In <Ubuntu>, untar it:

```
tar zxvf myfiles.tar.gz myfiles
```

Answer (score 3):

See also my similar question: [How to access \wsl$\othercontainer\some\file from within a WSL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67900684/how-to-access-wsl-othercontainer-some-file-from-within-a-wsl-container) where the short answer is:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/othercontainer
sudo mount -t drvfs '\\wsl$\othercontainer' /mnt/othercontainer
ls -l /mnt/othercontainer/some/file
```

**NOTE**: It looks like symbolic links aren't supported.

Comment: rights are not supported either