# How to access \\wsl$\othercontainer\some\file from within a WSL container?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

From Windows, I can access the file systems of all the WSL containers from under `\\wsl$`.

And from inside a WSL container, I can access the windows `C:\` drive as `/mnt/c`.

But how can I access another container's drive from inside a WSL container?

I'm trying to access `\\wsl$\othercontainer\some\file` from inside a WSL container.

`wslpath` can normally convert Windows file paths to paths accessible from WSL:

```
WSL2@~» wslpath 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

But it doesn't work for:

```
WSL2@~» wslpath '\\wsl$\othercontainer\some\file'
wslpath: \\wsl$\othercontainer\some\file

WSL2@~» echo $?
1
```

And of course:

```
WSL2@~» ls -l '\\wsl$\othercontainer\some\file'
ls: cannot access '\\wsl$\othercontainer\some\file': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Just a friendly, neighborhood reminder that questions on Stack Overflow should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: point taken. I've just found the answer myself. I'll post the answer and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1129533/how-to-access-drives-other-than-c-in-ubuntu-on-windows) provided the answer:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/othercontainer
sudo mount -t drvfs '\\wsl$\othercontainer' /mnt/othercontainer
ls -l /mnt/othercontainer/some/file
```

**NOTE**: It looks like symbolic links aren't supported. When one is encountered, we get an error like:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/othercontainer/bin

ls: cannot read symbolic link '/mnt/othercontainer/bin': Function not implemented
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 23  2020 /mnt/othercontainer/bin
```